# How to test single it() method from a specific spec.ts file

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to angular Unit testing using jasmine. Wondering if we can test a single it() method from a specific spec.ts file that consists of only one describe.

In order to test a single test case scenario every time I have to run **ng test** and wait for it to complete.

I researched a lot but no luck. I know we can change the karma configuration to a specific spec file and run but then curious to know if there is a way we can do like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run a specific test in jasmine, simple change `it()` to `fit()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use fdescribe instead of describe to run a single describe block

and fit instead of it to run a single test spec

f stands for focused and only these will run

and if you want run all just remove f from all specs